# How to local data storage and synchronization for a Flutter app using Node.js and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, dart

I'm using Node.js and MongoDB for my Flutter application. Currently, my app only retrieves data from the server. I want to store the data retrieved from the server locally on the phone and be able to synchronize data between local and server. What approach should I use? I want a cost-free method (even if it's difficult to implement) as I am developing a startup application.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of Databases out there,
But I suggest you using hive database which is NoSQL. the thing that you currently looking forward to implement is called caching and this database is
really awesome .less boiler plate and fast and easy to use